# Failed to push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push a rails app. This is my first time pushing to heroku and I keep getting a failed to push error. Below is the entire log. Not sure what to do, been trying to debug for a while now and am looking for some guidance. I've included the errors that arise while trying to push to heroku.

```
remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <main> at /tmp/build_8a642792/config/application.rb:7)
remote:        yarn install v1.22.4
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.10.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 26.00s.
remote:        yarn install v1.22.4
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        warning " > @babel/preset-react@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-self@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@7.10.5" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning "@babel/preset-react > @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx > @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@7.10.4" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@^7.0.0-0".
remote:        warning " > webpack-dev-server@3.11.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 5.13s.
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.537143 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.538661 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js.gz
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.539220 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/application-5f76c8eb924dd539ae8659076d9be5a4cdefaf9405f46bd5bb8d9598fcbbdb77.css
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.539955 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/application-5f76c8eb924dd539ae8659076d9be5a4cdefaf9405f46bd5bb8d9598fcbbdb77.css.gz
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.540716 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/footer-f06d1253d6f9956ed6472e503943aa4128336b81beeaf1104ccee464fb96b784.css
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.541559 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/footer-f06d1253d6f9956ed6472e503943aa4128336b81beeaf1104ccee464fb96b784.css.gz
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.542364 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/pages-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
remote:        I, [2020-07-22T23:46:21.542764 #1647]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a642792/public/assets/pages-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
remote:        Compiling...
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        Hash: 3460a868ed988e7f5861
remote:        Version: webpack 4.43.0
remote:        Time: 7753ms
remote:        Built at: 07/22/2020 11:46:31 PM
remote:         5 assets
remote:        Entrypoint application = js/application-d8b14a6d7311c26926b3.js js/application-d8b14a6d7311c26926b3.js.map
remote:        Entrypoint hello_react = js/hello_react-17885c96a612f595d1d0.js js/hello_react-17885c96a612f595d1d0.js.map
remote:        [3] ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 2.79 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
remote:        [4] ./app/javascript/packs/hello_react.jsx 615 bytes {1} [built]
remote:            + 7 hidden modules
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
remote:        SyntaxError: /tmp/build_8a642792/app/javascript/packs/application.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (19:8)
remote:        
remote:          17 | // const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
remote:          18 | 
remote:        > 19 | require jquery3
remote:             |         ^
remote:          20 | require popper
remote:          21 | require bootstrap
remote:          22 | 
remote:            at Object._raise (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:757:17)
remote:            at Object.raiseWithData (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:750:17)
remote:            at Object.raise (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:744:17)
remote:            at Object.unexpected (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8834:16)
remote:            at Object.semicolon (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:8816:40)
remote:            at Object.parseExpressionStatement (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11743:10)
remote:            at Object.parseStatementContent (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11344:19)
remote:            at Object.parseStatement (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11210:17)
remote:            at Object.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11785:25)
remote:            at Object.parseBlockBody (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11771:10)
remote:            at Object.parseTopLevel (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11141:10)
remote:            at Object.parse (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12843:10)
remote:            at parse (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12896:38)
remote:            at parser (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:54:34)
remote:            at parser.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at normalizeFile (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:93:38)
remote:            at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at run (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:31:50)
remote:            at run.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at Function.transform (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:27:41)
remote:            at transform.next (<anonymous>)
remote:            at step (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:254:32)
remote:            at /tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266:13
remote:            at async.call.result.err.err (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:11)
remote:            at /tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:184:28
remote:            at /tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/gensync-utils/async.js:72:7
remote:            at /tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:108:33
remote:            at step (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:280:14)
remote:            at /tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:266:13
remote:            at async.call.result.err.err (/tmp/build_8a642792/node_modules/gensync/index.js:216:11)
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to trevorblogger.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/trevorblogger.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/trevorblogger.git'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your javascript/packs/application.js file. Please verify and post the content here.

Comment: Hi @Luskmo. Thanks for replying. I looked in the folder and VScode recommended putting ";" on the three lines at the bottom of this code snippet. Was this the syntax error? I've never seen a semicolon put here before so it seems odd. I will test later today when I get off work.

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

require ;jquery3
require ;popper
require ;bootstrap
```